# The difference between playing video via URL and player

Tags: android, parsing, youtube, streaming, android-videoview

I'm developing an Android app that can parse both the Youtube and Dailymotion webpages,and render its URL of videos, but the buffering speed is not stable.

Sometimes, the video is buffered fast via its Website native player, but it is buffered slow in my Android Videoview.

How can I fix the problem, and what kind of difference is there between these two ways to play Video?

```
private class isConnected extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
Boolean result;
public isConnected(Boolean r)
{
    result = r;
}

protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
String getURL = params[0];
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(getURL);
HttpResponse responseGet = null;
try {
    responseGet = client.execute(get);
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error:" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
return false;
} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
//e.printStackTrace();
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error:" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
return false;
}
if(responseGet.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK)
    result = true;
else
    result = false;
return result;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Boolean r) {
// here you have the result
result = r;
    }
}
VideoView videoView;
String URL;
videoView.setVideoPath(URL);
myVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(
new OnPreparedListener() {
@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {

arg0.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new OnBufferingUpdateListener(){

@Override
public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Log.d("123","Buffer Percentage = " + percent);
}});

// TODO Auto-generated method stub
new isConnected(video_ready).execute(URL);
if (!video_ready)
{
    progDailog.dismiss();
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(HomeActivity.this);
    alert.setTitle("Warning").setMessage("The URL of video is incorrect.").setNeutralButton("OK", null);
    alert.create().show();                  
}
if (progDailog.isShowing()) 
{
    progDailog.dismiss();
}

videoView.start();

}
});
```

Comment: Please post some relevant code, are you using prepareAsync()?

Comment: I have posted the code, and I don't use prepareAsync(). Should I use it by some reasons?